# fetchall( ) not working on SQLite for certain records

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some data stored into a SQLite Database and a Python program that is supposed to retrieve them. The user inputs two dates (e.g. 01/01/2010 - 01/01/2013) and the program should make some analysis on the data going from 01/01/2010 to 01/01/2013.
The way the code is retrieving the data is the following:

```
con = lite.connect("data.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT ROWID from Table WHERE Date IS "01/01/2010"')
rowDate1 = cur.fetchall()

cur.execute('SELECT ROWID from Table WHERE Date IS "01/01/2013"')
rowDate2 = cur.fetchall()
```

The two variables `rowDate1` and `rowDate2` are the inferior and superior extremes to be used to execute the SQL statement that will give back the values to be used in the Python program.
Basically, if I want to run my analysis for the period 01/01/2010 - 01/01/2013, the variables `rowDate1` and `rowDate2` will contain the row IDs to be used for the data retrieving.

So, until a certain date, specifically 01/01/2010, the variable `rowDate1` is giving back the rowID number with the following sample output:

```
rowDate1 == [(6002,)]
```

After 01/01/2010, though, the return of the `cur.fetchall()` is empty: `rowDate1 = []`
I have checked the data into the database and they exist, they have a rowID exactly like the others. 
Moreover, if the data wouldn't exist, then even the variable `rowDate2` should return an empty value, which is not the case.
In fact, if I would execute:

```
cur.execute('SELECT ROWID from Table WHERE Date IS "01/01/2012"')
rowDate1 = cur.fetchall()
rowDate2 = cur.fetchall()
print rowDate1, rowDate2
```

I would get the following output:

```
[] [(6002,)]
```

I know, it's absurde, but I really don't understand how this could happen.
I fear this is a bug of the code and I've really no clue. Does anyone have an idea of how can I move to detect it, what it could depend on?

**NOTE**: there is not really much more I can post about the remaining part of the code. Exactly the same statement works in the attribution of the variable `rowDate2` and not in the variable `rowDate1`; I mean, if I input from the GUI the date frame "01/01/2012 - 01/01/2012", the variable `rowDate1` won't have a value while the variable `rowDate2` will. But it's weird because they are the same statements, just the `rowDate1` is executed before!?

**COMPLETE CODE**:

```
con = None  
con = lite.connect(dPath.adresseBDD + '/' + symb + '.db')                 
cur = con.cursor()    

cur.execute('SELECT ROWID from ' + frequence + ' WHERE Date IS "' + date1+'"' )                 
rowDate1= cur.fetchall() 

cur.execute('SELECT ROWID from ' + frequence + ' WHERE Date IS "' + date2+'"' ) 
rowDate2= cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Your post contains syntax errors because your queries are not properly quoted. Can you fix this please? Also, your SQL query is incorrect; you cannot use `IS` to test for column equality. You'd use `Date = "01/01/2010"` instead.

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't notice it

Comment: There is no difference between the two queries other than the date literals. This simply means that SQLite doesn't think there are any rows matching that query, so the assumption about there being rows that do match incorrect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even if I change the statement to `Date = "01/01/2010"` is not changing the return value. It seems it works the same. As for your second comment, I didn't understand what you mean. How can SQLite thinks something different about the same statement?

Comment: Your post is unclear. You are saying that `rowDate2 = cur.fetchall()` *clears `rowDate1`? Or sets `rowDate2` to something other than an empty list? What exactly happens, can you show us the results as Python would print them?

Comment: I made some edits to the question, I think now is a bit more clear.

Comment: Are you **really** first getting an empty list *then* the data? Please post your actual code and outcomes, because this makes less and less sense.

Comment: I posted the full part code (didn't skip anything) where the problem occurs. Martjin, if it would have made sense I wouldn't have said it was a very weird problem ;)

Comment: I was talking about your `rowDate1 = cur.fetchall(); rowDate2 = cur.fetchall(); print rowDate1, rowDate2` claim that it prints `[], [(6002,)]`; that would almost certainly be the other way around.

Comment: By the way, this is happening with some records only, as I stated in the title of my question. For example, if I run the same while inputting "01/01/2009" this does not happen :/

Comment: I am trying to establish what `rowDate2` prints in your actual code; is it an empty list or not?

Comment: Oh ok, I cannot post that part cause I'm developing in Aptana Studio 3.0 and that was something I wrote in the console while debugging. Unfortunately I cannot give you the script cause you would need the project in debug mode to run it with a result. I've tried again, it's exactly `print rowDate1, rowDate2`

Comment: No, `rowDate2` is not empty while `rowDate1` is.

Comment: What is the value returned by the query `SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Date = '01/01/2010'`?

Comment: @CL. the value returned from the query you told me is `[(1,)]`